# Convert string to char

Tags: c#

I get from another class string that must be converted to char. It usually contains only one char and that's not a problem. But control chars i receive like '\\n' or '\\t'. 
Is there standard methods to convert this to endline or tab char or i need to parse it myself?

edit:
Sorry, parser eat one slash. I receive '\\t'

Comment: The class you are receiving the string from is doing something non-standard so the characters are no longer control characters, they've been converted (unneccesarily) to a longer literal string. You'll just have to have a special case to handle them.

Comment: this looks familiar!: http://www.infoqu.com/dev/c-programming/weeding-out-control-characters-in-c-30095-1/

Comment: May be a stupid question, but are you looking at the value in a watch window? The watch window will add an extra \ so are you sure the string is "\\t"?

Comment: Sure. I understand why this happens. That class reads values from file, if user add to file '\t'  it will be parse as two chars '\' and 't'.

Comment: there is a danger that you are just confusing us all, when you say - the user adds '\t' - do you mean that they type a slash and a letter t, or do you mean they add a Tab (control character)?

Comment: OK.
We got config file with string <delimeter>\t</delimeter>
that means that user wants TAB as delimiter.

XmlSerializer deserialize it as two  chars '\' and  't', but i want tab

Comment: Ok, so my answer seems to be your best option.

Comment: unless you want to get involved in intercepting some of the hooks (events) in the XMLSerializer and adding your own logic, but you'd still need to do a string.Replace there too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New line:

```
string escapedNewline = @"\\n";
string cleanupNewLine = escapedNewline.Replace(@"\\n", Environment.NewLine);
```

OR

```
string cleanupNewLine = escapedNewline.Replace(@"\\n", "\n");
```

Tab:

```
string escapedTab = @"\\t";
string cleanupTab= escapedTab.Replace(@"\\t", "\t");
```

Note the lack of the literal string (i.e. i did not use @"\t" because that will not represent a Tab)

Alternatively you could consider [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html) if you need to replace a range of different string patterns.

You should probably write a utility function to encapsulate the common behaviour above for all the possible [Escape Sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

Then you'd write some [Unit Tests](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UnitTest) to cover each of the cases you can think of.

As you encounter any bugs you add more unit tests to cover those cases.

**UPDATE**

You could represent a tab in the XML with a special character sequence:

`&#x9;` [see this article](http://recycledknowledge.blogspot.com/2006/03/writing-out-xml.html)

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180886.aspx) applies to SQL Server but may well be relevant to C# also?

To be absolutely sure, you could try generating a string with a tab in it and putting it into some XML (programmatically) and using XmlSerializer to serialize that to a file to see what the output is, then you can be sure that this will faithfully 'round-trip' the string with the tab still in it.

Comment: Seems that this is only available variant.

Answer (score 18):

I assume that you mean that the class that sends you the data is sending you a string like "\n". In that case you have to parse this yourself using:

```
Char.Parse(returnedChar)
```

Otherwise you can just cast it to a string like this

```
(string)returnedChar
```

Comment: That class reads it from file. So if file contains \n i receive \\n thats my trouble.

Answer (score 5):

how about using `string.ToCharArray()`

You can then add the appropriate logic to process whatever was in the string.

Answer (score 2):

char.parse(string); is used to convert string to char and you can do vice versa 
char.tostring(); 
100% solved